# How to manipulate the SQL Server database from grid view (Form Application in VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net

I need to control a database from grid view.

In another article I have to see how to manipulate a database, but there still used textbox and button for next process. In my case I need to control the data from grid view, so tell me please if you have solution for this problem.

Specifications:

- application form
- visual basic .NET 2010
- SQL Server database

Answer (score 0):

A quick search online found this: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/395019/how-to-use-grid-view-with-vb-net).  Below is the example code from that link showing how to display data.

If you want to do CRUD, please take a look at the Microsoft example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx).

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="Your .mdb path";"
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Authors"
        Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        Dim dataadapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        connection.Open()
        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Authors_table")
        connection.Close()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
        DataGridView1.DataMember = "Authors_table"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I have to try your code. but this is just showing to display data from database.

Comment: thanks , I will looking for the tutorial in microsoft example. if you know the answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428863/tell-me-for-make-link-from-gridview-in-vb-net-2012-windows-form , please tell me ...