# Making a link from GridView in VB.NET 2012 (Windows Form)

Tags: vb.net

I have project to develop an application for employees and schedule management on my campus. My plan is to develop with VB.NET and use SQL Server for the database.

How can I use a grid view to make a link going to another window? The window will show all information by schedule.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [DataGridViewLinkColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewlinkcolumn.aspx). Also check [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/61443472-72b5-4202-a4c0-54cca77e13eb/) link.

Once `CellContentClick` event fires, you can create another form and pass desired values to that form to display details and show them up.

You can also use `DataGridViewButtonColumn` too.

EDIT:

I assume that I have two forms `frmMaster` and `frmDetails`. DataGridView lies on `frmMaster` and user keeps record `ID` in `TAG` property of first cell.

then, FrmMaster code would be:

```
Private Sub frmMaster_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        ' Added a LinkColumn from code (you can do it at design time too)
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewLinkColumn() With {.Text = "Show details"})
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    Dim detail As New frmDetail()     ' create an instance of detail form
    detail.ID = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Tag'set property of detail form
    detail.ShowDialog()   ' Show form
End Sub
```

and `frmdetail` code would be:

```
 Private _Id As String
    Public Property ID() As String
        Get
            Return _Id
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Id = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub frmDetail_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LoadData(_Id)
    End Sub

    Sub LoadData(ByVal _id As Integer)
        '' use '_id' variable to extract data from dtaabse via query
    End Sub
```